# Quickblox chat channel stopped working after 2 days

Tags: quickblox

I have a quickblox account that we're using internally for testing. Very low throughput (Total of around 600 messages across 2 days and never more than a 3 or 4 per second at the very peak.)

Today the messages stopped sending in the chatroom. There doesn't appear to be any errors coming through the network panel of chrome and no errors popping up in the admin panel.

As a test, without changing any client code, I created a new room and simply updated my config so my client pointed there. This worked with absolutely no problems.

Are there any things I may be missing here? Is this possibly a free tier thing where only a few hundred messages may be sent at any one time or is this more likely something client side?

Answer (score 0):

It were some maintenance periods, you should receive emails about it.

So maybe you were trying to use chat during that period.

600 messages across 2 days it's very small value, so no problems here with limits.

Comment: It's not maintenance related. Still haven't gotten to the bottom of it but it may have something to do with poorly escaped messages causing undocumented (or poorly documented) results within underlying libraries. Still digging but that at least appears to be the case.